# Spoon.batch file not launching software

Tags: installation, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I downloaded Pentaho Data Integration (or Kettle) to my Windows 10 machine from the [sourceforge link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/7.1/pdi-ce-7.1.0.0-12.zip/download) on the [Pentaho Community website](http://community.pentaho.com/). After unzipping the files I followed the instructions on the community website for launching the software, quoted here:

> After unzipping the downloaded file, you can launch Spoon by navigating to the folder /data-integration and double clicking Spoon.bat

My OS doesn't recognize any .bat file in the specified folder, but a Windows Batch File of the same name is in the folder, and it has the same size (4 KB) which the `Spoon.bat` file is meant to have, so I believe it is the same file referred to in the instructions.

Opening this file seems to execute the batch instruction in a command prompt window which immediatey disappears. No other effect is observed; in particular, no software is launched.

I googled and found that a common cause for issues of this kind is not having the a 64-bit version of java installed. So I installed a 64-bit version of the java runtime environment from [this link](http://download.cnet.com/Java-Runtime-Environment-JRE-64-Bit/3000-2378_4-75317067.html) and followed the approach described in [this forum post](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?200911-Spoon-won-t-start-Windows-10) for putting links to the java executables in the path that pentaho expects.

This had no effect, even after I restarted my computer.

Is there a simpler way to get this software working that I don't know about, or a step that I've missed here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing that got it working for me was to follow the advice in [this post](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?198116-PDI-6-does-not-start) which specifies modifying the Spoon batch file by replacing `-Xmx2048m` with `-Xmx1024m` in the string

> if: "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

(because 32-bit java cannot handle the 2048m).

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution. Spoon.bat and set-pentaho-env.bat go through a whole routine looking for a usable Java version. Somehow it's finding the 32-bit before the 64-bit version. Running the batch file from a command line window should show you how it does that.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree this is just a workaround. I was disappointed to see how difficult it was to just get the software setup and start working with it. I will probably not spend more time trying to find a solution as I do have the workaround and have spent so much time already. Hopefully the next version will have these issues sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

It's been four years but I'm commenting in case someone else finds this when looking for the answer:
I solved the issue by downloading the JAVA 64bit > installing in Program Files > DELETING the 32bit in Program Files(x86) > and then replacing the Program Files (x86) with the 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Does your batch-file contain a space in the name? For me that was causing a launch problem.

Comment: Hmmm, that is strange that yours did, but no, mine didn't. Did you download from the same link I posted above?